# Searching for a substring in one of the columns

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm writing an Andriod app, and I'd like to see if there is a quick way for this.  I don't really want to split the whole string into multiple array elements, as the contents might contain non-English characters.

I've tried to use whereContains("myColumn", ), but it doesn't return any result.  Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Perhaps if you can post the code that you have, we can suggest changes on top of that.

Comment: Please explain your question...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a SQL query why not use the `LIKE`

For example

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name LIKE '%your_sub_string%';
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tags you placed, I assume you are talking about `Parse`.

Try this:

```
yourQuery.whereMatches(<yourfield>,<text you are searching>, "im");
```

See http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereMatches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Example:

```
titleQuery.whereMatches("title", "hello", "im");
```

i - Case insensitive search

m - Search across multiple lines of input